# observable undefined in component - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

**I have a service that connects with api**

```
export class ConsolidadoApi {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getInvestiments(search?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.basePosicaoConsolidada}`);
  }
}
```

Response this api:

https://demo5095413.mockable.io/consolidado

**This one is responsible for the logic before reaching the component**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreService {
    public test;
    constructor(private api: ConsolidadoApi, private state: StateService) { }

public createMenu() {
    this.api.getInvestiments()
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response.carteiras[0])
           this.products = response.carteiras[0]
           return this.products;
        })
}
```

**In my component**

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private coreService : CoreService ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.coreService.createMenu())
  }

}
```

***But when createMenu is called in menu.component.ts it comes undefined.***

[image]

Comment: The expression `this.test = response;`. doesnt handle the scenario when response is undefined.

Comment: But even when I use response.forEach, it goes undefined

Comment: You could silently hide the problem with coalescing to empty array `this.test = response || [];`. Do you expect that response might return `undefined`?

Comment: No, I need the data coming out of the API to get to the component.

Comment: Whats inside `this.api.getInvestiments()`?

Comment: This response: http://demo5095413.mockable.io/carteira-investimentos

Comment: Please update the question description with json sample.

Comment: One of the problems was answered by @Nikhil VS, but the data is still undefined in the component

Comment: createMenu() doesn't actually return anything..?

Comment: Updated a question with result createMenu() in component

Comment: check the spelling once. In the console its displaying as "categorias" but in the service you are accessing "response.carteiras[0]"

Comment: updated link api for a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

The raw response is an object. forEach works only on an array. If you are aiming for forEach in 'categorias', you should try

```
this.test.categorias.forEach()
```

Comment: Very good, I managed to solve the foreach problem, but I still couldn't get the data to the component, it's still undefined

Comment: Could you please post the html part ?

Comment: But it is not arriving at menu.component.ts, How to receive first on menu.compoent.ts? I try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393346/observable-undefinded-in-facade-architeture-with-rxjs

Comment: Could you please check the backend for this?
Maybe they are not handling it well.
I mean if the response is undefined, then there is somthing fishy

Comment: Updated a question with result createMenu() in component

Answer (score 1):

When you return `Observable<any>`, that means the argument of the lambda you create when you do `subscribe` (which you named `response`) is type `any`. This doesn't necessary have the function `forEach` defined (unless the API returns an object with that prototype). That's generally why using `any` is not good practice; you can't have any expectations on what the object can contain. In fact, it's possible that it's not on object (it could be an array since `any` is not exclusively an object). If you do want to use `forEach`, you will want to make sure that `response` is type `array`. You can inspect the object's type before using it (e.g. using `typeof`) and make a judgement on what to call or even just check if the function you're trying to use is defined first, e.g. `if (response.forEach !== undefined)`. You don't actually need to compare to undefined though, so `if (response.forEach)` suffices. In the examples, I used `response`, but you can use `this.test` since they are the same object after the first line in the lambda.

Comment: Very good, I managed to solve the foreach problem, but I still couldn't get the data to the component, it's still undefined. How can i solve it?

Comment: The `console.log` in `MenuComponent` can only print something if `createMenu` returns a value, which it doesn't.

Comment: Updated a question with result createMenu() in component

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas You need to have a `return` statement in `createMenu` for the `console.log` to print.

Comment: Oh Sorry, add return this.products, but not working :(

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas `this.products` is set sometime in the future and you'll have to wait for the request to complete before reading the value. I would suggest either subscribing to the observable in the menu class so you can directly retrieve the value when it's ready or having your service class emit an event when the values are updated and you subscribe to that event.

Comment: Good idea, could you show an example how I can do this? How can I declare the createMenu response and a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas that return statement actually for the lambda and not for the outer function (`createMenu`).

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas in your service class, make a new class member such as `public menuUpdated: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter`. Then in your `createMenu` function, in the lambda, after you set `this.products`, you can do `this.menuReady.emit()`. The argument is type any, so you can pass anything in there. In your `MenuComponent` you can then `subscribe` to `CoreService.menuReady` and either read from `this.coreService.products` or pass some value through the event emitter (such as `this.products` in the service class) and that will  be the argument of the lambda in your `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you shared, the response is an object. You can log it to the console to confirm.

You can only call for each on an array, so for example, based on the response api, you can call forEach on the property ‘categorias’ and on that array’s children property ‘produtus’

Edit: this answer was based on the op original api and question

https://demo5095413.mockable.io/carteira-investimentos

```
    public createMenu() {
        return this.api.getInvestiments()
       }

    ngOnit() {
        this.coreService.createMenu().subscribe(x => console.log(x.categorias))};




{
 "codigo":1,
 "categorias":[
    {
       "nome":"Referenciado",
       "valorTotal":23000.0,
       "codigo":"2",
       "produtos":[
          {
           "nome":"CDB FÃƒÂ¡cil Bradesco",
           "valor":2000.0,
           "codigo":1,
           "quantidade":0.0,
           "porcentagem":0.5500,
           "aplicacaoAdicional":500.0,
           "codigoInvest":1,
           "salaInvestimento":"CDB",
           "permiteAplicar":true,
           "permiteResgatar":true,
           "movimentacaoAutomatica":false,
           "ordemApresentacao":37,
           "horarioAbertura":"08:30",
           "horarioFechamento":"23:59",
           "codigoGrupo":0,
           "codigoMF":"001
```

Comment: Very good, I managed to solve the foreach problem, but I still couldn't get the data to the component, it's still undefined. How can i solve it?

Comment: I would suggest logging the response to see what you are getting from the api.

Comment: yes, I have api data in core.service.ts but when I access this service in the component it appears undefined.

Comment: Please clarify what is undefined, the CoreService or the response?

Comment: Updated a question with result createMenu() in component

Comment: Because the createMenu function doesn’t returned anything so it logs undefined.

Comment: Oh Sorry, add return this.products, but not working :(

Comment: See my edited answer, return the subscription, subscribe in the component and set the component property to the desired info

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas check the spelling once. In the console its displaying as "categorias" but in the service you are accessing "response.carteiras[0]"

Comment: @Lee I tried what you put in the answer, but it still comes undefined.

Comment: What comes undefined?

Comment: As @sivapagolu mentioned, are you logging the correct property?

Comment: Do you want response.carteiras[0] or response.carteiras[0].categorias? I think your question is worded very poorly.